# How to add dynamically add to DOM on click?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a form where there is a an input. The user can click an add button and another input will appear under it and so on.
The problem I am having is how do I add an input to the DOM on a click event.

My first thought was using an ngFor or v-for (I'm using both, answer can be in either). When I click the add button, it increments a counter and the counter is then pushed into an array. Then using the for it will display the inputs.

```
let inputs = 0;
addInput() {
  this.inputs++;
  this.criteria.push(this.inputs);
}
```

```
<button @click.prevent='addInput'>Add input</button>

<input type='text' value='Default Input'>
<div v-for="input in inputs" v-bind:key="input">
   <input type='text'>
</div>
```

It works as originally thought. A new input appears when the button is clicked.

The problem occurs when I add a second input, enter a value, then add a third input. The second input's value is reset to blank.

How can I implement this feature, adding inputs on click, but saving the values on the previous inputs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind the value of the input (using `v-model`) to a value in your `inputs` array, it should keep your values - even when adding a new input.

```
let inputs = [];
addInput() {
  this.inputs.push({value: ""});
}
```

```
<button @click.prevent='addInput'>Add input</button>

<input type='text' value='Default Input'>
<div v-for="(input, index) in inputs" v-bind:key="index">
   <input v-model="input.value" type='text'>
</div>
```